# Yii2 --- PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'unserialize(): Error at offset 8189 of 8192 bytes'

Tags: php, yii2

```
PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'unserialize(): Error at offset 8189 of 8192 bytes' 

in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\controllers\DefaultController.php:132

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'unserialize(): ...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 132, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\controllers\DefaultController.php(132): unserialize('a:58:{s:13:"55a...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\controllers\DefaultController.php(147): yii\debug\controllers\DefaultController->getManifest(false)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\controllers\DefaultController.php(92): yii\debug\controllers\DefaultController->loadData('55a8abf042085', 5)
#4 [internal function]: yii\debug\controllers\DefaultController->actionToolbar('55a8abf042085')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(151): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('toolbar', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('debug/default/t...', Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\advanced\backend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

Getting this error while running Yii2 application whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Remove `runtime/debug/index.data` file and try again

Comment: It get solved.. thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks @NgôVănThao that solved the issue immediately, took me a minute to realise it was located in the root directory, I was looking in the vendor sub folders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a problem in the cached version of the request data. You could try clearing the folder under `@runtime/debug`.

Comment: It is still occurring after deleting whole folder

Answer (score 0):

If you use Files caching, empty the `@runtime/cache` folder.