# Yiii2 - 500 internal error

Tags: apache, yii2, http-status-code-404, internal-server-error

someone gave a copy of a project created with yii2 and I had to Execute composer to get all the packages for the project, but I get this error:

[image]

This is what I get in the Runtime/app.log file:

```
[127.0.0.1][-][-][error][yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Page not found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba-desarrolladores\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:189
```

I haven't been able to access the main view of the project. I've been looking at the related post in here, but nothing works I have no idea what to do, thanks for the help.

Comment: 500 is the error code of an php exception. Can you give us more informations? Perhaps there is just a syntax error.

Comment: check runtime/logs/app.log

Comment: This means that the path to your web comparing to your friend's web is different.

Comment: You have 2 different errors. 1st the url does not match any of your routes and 2nd the debug toolbar of yii2 is not working. Can you provide your route settings? Check "urlManager" setting in your config files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this twice.Firstly I seen my "Network Tab" in Chrome Developer Options and it said:
`PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 16105 bytes'`
I was delete my cookies with [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) Chrome extension and solved temporary.Tomorrow day I had this error again and I found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470411/yii2-php-notice-yii-base-errorexception-with-message-unserialize-error) and I delete my project `runtime/debug` folder and my problem solved.